# How to change the default caret in a Java application?

Tags: java, caret

I have seen examples that changes the default caret of a single JTextField but is there any function or code that changes the default caret of the whole application to another caret?

Answer (score 1):

[Component.setCursor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setCursor(java.awt.Cursor)) is the API that you can use to set the cursor/caret of your choice. However, you should note the contract of this API.

> Setting the cursor of a Container causes that cursor to be displayed within all of the container's subcomponents, except for those that have a non-null cursor.

So setting the cursor on the top-most container should probably do it unless it is set in child components.

Note that if you want to create a custom cursor, you would have to use [Toolkit.createCustomCursor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#createCustomCursor(java.awt.Image,%20java.awt.Point,%20java.lang.String))

Hope this helps.